# How do I force a function to break if one part errors

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get my function to break and echo when an error occurs in one of the called upon scripts. I can't get it to work...

```
function FOOBAR($v1, $v2, $v3, $v4) {

    try{Python foo.py $v1 $v3 $v4 | Out-Host}
    catch { echo "foo.py failed"
        break}

    try{Python bar.py $v1 $v2 $v3 | Out-Host}
    catch { echo "bar.py failed"
        break}

    try{Invoke-Expression -Command "foo.ps1 $v1 $v2 $v3 $v4" | Out-Host}
    catch { echo "foo.ps1 failed"
        break}

    try{Invoke-Expression -Command "bar.ps1 $v2 $v3 $v4" | Out-Host}
    catch { echo "bar.ps1 failed"
        break}
}
```

Comment: I would be surprised if `python.exe` threw a terminating error if it fails. It may give some non-zero exit code, though (which you can test with `$?`).

Comment: It is working as expected. If the foo.py is failing it is breaking the entire function FOOBAR. if you remove the break then all will get executed. But as per your expectation it should break, so its working. I f you want I can post answer with screenshot for the same.

Comment: The `return` statement will exit a function. If you wish you can return the echoed comment also

Comment: You can try using Trap also.

Breaking:
`function breaking { 
trap {"Error has been trapped"; break;}
 1/$null ;
 "Function execution over."
 }`

Continuing:

 `function continuing{
 trap {"Error trapped"; continue;}
 1/$null ;
"Function completed."
}`